# How to change the heights in column of CSV file to inches

Tags: python, pandas

I am extremely new to both Python, Pandas, etc.

I am trying to convert the 'height' column to just inches.

First, I am stuck and have this code so far, it seem to kind of work but it does not anymore. There is one `NaN` value in the column, so I tried to skip over that row.

Second, after I get the code to work, how to do I change the original CSV and not my Pandas DataFrame.

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/drgilermo/nba-players-stats#player_data.csv) is link to data set and this is the code I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r"C:\Users\jackw\Downloads\player_data.csv"
bball_data = pd.read_csv(filename)

df = pd.DataFrame(bball_data)


def height_convert(player_height):
    player_height = str(player_height)

    feet = float(player_height[0])
    inches = float(player_height[-1])

    new_height = float((feet * 12) + inches)

    return new_height


for value in df['height']:

    if value[0] != ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'):
        continue
    value = height_convert(value)
```

Comment: Instead of `!=` you might want `not in` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work because you're retrieving the inch component of the strings using `player_height[-1]` which will get you the last character. But there's 12 inches in a foot so if a player is '6-12' you will incorrectly read this as 6'2".

A better solution would be to split the strings on the hyphen ('-') character and separate the values that way. Here's a way of doing so using list comprehensions.

```
import pandas as pd

# read data
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/player_data.csv')

# drop rows with no height data
df = df.dropna(subset=['height'])     

# split the strings
df.height = [s.split('-') for s in df.height]
# convert to inches
df.height = [float(value[0])*12 + float(value[1]) for value in df.height]

# write data
df.to_csv('Desktop/player_data_updated.csv', index=False)
```

Also when you read a csv file into Python you're not working on that file per se but a version of it saved into memory. The csv file will remain untouched unless you save it to a file again at the end.